# PHP date conversion dd [th/st/rd] / month / yyyy

Tags: php, date

I have my users entering the date in this format :- `mm/dd/yyyy (11/21/2012)`

My PHP script converts the date into the following format :- `dd-Month-yyyy (21-November-2012)`

I do this using :-

```
$new_date = date('d-F-Y', strtotime($user_date));
```

How can I have the date in this format :- `21st November 2012`?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert one date format into another in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2167916/convert-one-date-format-into-another-in-php)

Answer (score 90):

You can use `S` letter as following:

```
$new_date = date('jS F Y', strtotime($user_date));
```

Check [manual](http://php.net/date).

Comment: If you find my answer correct, mark the check under the answer's score.

Comment: Also better to use `j` if you want "1st" instead of "01st" appearing in your dates: `$new_date = date('jS F Y', strtotime($user_date));`

Comment: `j<\s\u\p>S</\s\u\p>` looks even better with `st`, `nd`, `rd` at the **top-right** of the day number

Answer (score 22):

It will output as you expect

```
$my_date = '2016-01-01';

echo date('F jS, Y', strtotime($my_date));
# January 1st, 2016
```

while ***dS*** will also prepends ***0***

```
echo date('F dS, Y', strtotime($my_date));
# January 01st, 2016
```

Answer (score 9):

```
$new_date = date('jS F Y', strtotime($date));
```

`S` - English ordinal suffix for the day of the month, 2 characters 
(**st**, **nd**, **rd** or **th**. Works well with **j**)

Answer (score 4):

```
**My Date = 22-12-1992**
<?php
    $mydate = "22-12-1992";
    $newDate = date("d M Y", strtotime($mydate));
    $new_date = date('dS F Y', strtotime($newDate));
    echo $new_date;
?>

**OutPut = 22nd December 1992**
```

Answer (score 4):

You can do that :

```
<?php echo date('dS M. Y');?>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use something like:

```
echo date('l, F jS');
```

Or even get a bit fancy with the HTML:

```
echo date('l, F j<\s\u\p>S</\s\u\p>');
```

Comment: Thanks.. The superscript with escaped slashes is real handy.

Answer (score 0):

`$date = date_create('09-22-2012');

 echo $date->format('d S F Y');`
by this code you will get your desire

for more you can also visit http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.date.php